# regex pattern for url with no ending slash and exclude certain text in url

Tags: regex

I'm looking for preg_match_all pattern to find all URL on a page that don't have trailing slash.

For example: if I have

```
a href="/testing/abc/">end with slash

a href="/testing/test/mnl">no ending slash
```

The result would be #2. Solution is posted at [find pattern for url with no ending slash](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15414909/find-pattern-for-url-with-no-ending-slash)

I have tried to modify the provided pattern to exclude urls that have 'images' or '.pdf' but no luck yet.

Thanks.

Comment: Which one you tried already?

Comment: /href=(["])[^\s]+(?<!\.pdf)(?<!images)(?<!\/)\1/

Comment: Before using any regex, use a HTML parser (DOMDocument) to parse the page, then pick out the tags that you want to process and check the href/src.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one should suit your needs ([demo](http://regexr.com?346iv)):

```
href="(?:(?<!images).(?!(?:[.]pdf|/)"))*?"
```

- `(?:)` = non-capturing groupe
- `(?<!images).` = any char not preceded by `images`
- `.(?!(?:[.]pdf|/)")` = any char not followed by `.pdf"` nor by `/"`
- `*?` = *match as short as possible*

Comment: Why the character class, `[.]`? Oh, I see. I've never seen anyone escape the `.` by a character class. Neat.

Comment: @acheong87 It's a way to escape the `.` special char. Just the same as `\.`, but I find it more *readable* ;)

Comment: Yeah, realized a second after I commented. Very nice regex; ingenious method.

Comment: @acheong87 I realized that you realized a second after I commented too ;)

Comment: Hi sp00m! this pattern will include url with trailing slash. How to work that one in? Thanks.

Comment: @sp00m, i'm testing by adding more conditions. Any suggestions:
/href="(?: (?<!images2) (?<!images).(?!(?:[.]xml|[.]js|[.]pdf|/)"))*?"/

Answer (score 1):

I found a way to exclude a link that has .pdf, by modifying the provided answer from the other question.
Still looking at why it won't not match the images example though.

```
href=(['"])[^\s]+(?<![\/]|.pdf)\1
```

Link to a working test http://www.rubular.com/r/jmBVstpGZD

Comment: This regex would reject .bmp and .tif as well. Can you figure out why? :)

Comment: hi zack, how about also exclude url that has 'images' (string) in it?

Comment: @acheong87 No I really have no idea oh cryptic master. :p I'm assuming you do know, and can provide some reasoning or possibly a link to why.

Comment: Haha, it's because `[.pdf]` is a character class that means "any _one_ of the characters, `.`, `p`, `d`, and `f`." You excluded anything that ended in one of those characters. What you meant is `\.pdf` without the square brackets. Sorry, didn't mean to leave you hangin'.

Comment: @acheong87 I see what you mean now. I updated my answer just so if anyone saw it they wouldn't try to use it. And because it was incorrect. Thanks for your explanation! I don't use regex much and posted before I tested it I guess.

Comment: Nice. No worries; all here to learn. 'cept Jon Skeet, I mean.